# PyCharm is giving an unused import error for routes, and models

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a basic Flask project. Here is the app.py file.

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_login import LoginManager


    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'sqlite:///my_database.db'

    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    login = LoginManager(app)

    login.login_view = 'login'

    import routes, models
```

PyCharm is telling me that route, and models are unused imports. They are located in the same root directory together. I'm not sure how to get these imported another way without having a circular import error.

Comment: Discard the last line `import routes, models` and create your routes and models in `app.py`.  Your entire application would be in one flask file

Comment: The reason I want them in separate folders is because they are going to get rather large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ideal way would be to use this structure where each module is separately handled:

```
project_folder
    |---------- app.py
    |---------- config.py
    |---------- .env
    |---------- requirements.txt
    |---------- .flaskenv
    |---------- app/
                  |------ routes.py
                  |------ models.py
                  |------ __init__.py
                  |------ forms.py
                  |------ templates/
                              |-------- base.html
                              |-------- index.html
                              |-------- test.html
                  |------ static/
                            |-------css/
                                     |------- styles.css
                            |-------js/
                                     |------- app.js
```

From `__init__.py`, you will create an instance of your flask app:

```py
from flask import Flask    
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'


from app import routes, models
```

Importing `routes` and `models` (and any other module you might have) at the bottom of `__init__.py` helps avoid circular dependencies issue.

The `app.py` is left as an entry point to your application:

```py
from app import app
```

Your configurations will go the `config.py` file:

```py
import os 

class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
    # ...
```